# Conditional Formatting Multiple Cell formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am having issues trying to accomplish the following,

```
1           
2           
3           
4           
5           
6
```

Having the above cell highlight based on approved criteria.

```
If cell G29 is above 10 to 19.99 then it equals A31 = 1     
If cell G29 is above 20 to 29.99 then it equals A32 = 2 
If cell G29 is above 30 to 30.99 then it equals A33 = 3 
If cell G29 is above 40 to 40.99 then it equals A34 = 4 
If cell G29 is above 50 to 50.99 then it equals A35 = 5 
If cell G29 is above 60 and above then it equals A36 = 6
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This doesn't seem like a conditional formatting issue...

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the value of one cell based on the value in another cell?  E.g. "=IF(AND(A31>10,A31<=19.99),1,0)

Comment: So in the example, G29 would fill based on the criteria of all A31 - A36 ie if the value of G29 is 44 then then the A34 value of 4

Comment: If G29 is 44, then it will populate 4 in a totals cell B30, If g29 is 65 then B30 would be 6

Comment: Number   
      0 up to 60   1.00
      61 up to 80   2.00
      81 up to 90   3.00
      91 up to 100   4.00
    Calclated Number based on E71  2.00
         
         
        
  E71 = 70.00

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i wish i could send you an example in excel.

Comment: just post a link to a picture.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P8av93rbbA0WdmmZ1Vo1uHLH4tHVNmVRibXpOatm9jU/edit#gid=0

Comment: it is shared now

Comment: Great help today, It is done!! thank you soooo much Goose !!